# Live bookmark for question in Chinese

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, languages

Sorry if I am off topic, but this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146446/

on my firefox 3.5.1 looks in the live bookmark like something in Chinese.

Comment: That's Chinese!

Answer (score 1):

It originally WAS all in Chinese. It then got closed and I am going to assume that stone (the OP) translated, editted, and it got reopened.

You can see the [Revision List](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1146446/list) for yourself.

Comment: Shame they removed all of the Japanse. Would have been interesting to read a bilingual question.